# Excel: Mirrored cells from one column to another, changes reflect automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I thought this would be a simple one but I can't seem to find the answer online. I have a column of data on Sheet1 (column A) and I'd like column A on Sheet2 to be exactly the same and any changes made to Sheet1 Column A will automatically be reflected in the mirrored Sheet2 Column a. Is there any way to do this other than VBA WorksheetChange?

Comment: Apply a Formula on Sheet2 Column A. `=Sheet1!A1` and drag it down.

Comment: See comment on the answer by chucklukowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Sheet2!A1` put the formula `=Sheet1!A1` and drag down. Should mirror the column from Sheet1. This will mirror the column and will update on any changes. Only issue I can think of is that deleting/inserting rows might cause problems.

Comment: I tried this one, I'm having 2 issues with it. It does bring across the value correctly, but when I drag it down it just duplicates the same value, it doesn't match what is on Sheet1. But more importantly, if I then go and change the value in Sheet1, it doesn't change it on Sheet2

Comment: Is the Formula -> Calculation Options set to Automatic? Also, what is the formula you have in B1 after dragging the formula down?

Comment: Is there a way to apply that to the entire column? Or at least the length of where the data is coming from on Sheet1? This is so if people are adding data into Sheet1, they don't need to drag it down on Sheet2, it should just appear

Comment: Would depend on what your process is. Can you put the formula before they get the file?

Comment: I ended up just doing it for 1000 rows and when it produced 0's I edited the formatting so it took them away - seems to have sorted it!

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A1),"",Sheet1!A1)

Comment: This turns the 0 into 'True'

Comment: Might have a typo, IF Sheet1A1 is Blank, THEN return empty string "", ELSE return the value in Sheet1A1. If you changed your formatting previously, that might be changing your result, now?